# Тонкости перевода

Tags: переводы

Мне не раз приходилось переводить с английского различные литературные тексты и, соответственно, читать чужие переводы. Надо сказать, что английские язык достаточно беден на передачу оттенков речи и ее характера, либо эти оттенки передаются не так, как в русском. Я обычно стараюсь адаптировать свой перевод под привычную нам речь - то есть, подбирать аналоги поговорок (если это не принципиально в оригинале), использовать какие-то наши формы словообразования, междометия и т.д. Само собой, с сохранением смысла и настроения оригинала.
У других же я часто вижу фактически подстрочник. Вот пример. Герой заходит в комнату и видит, что в ней что-то не так. Соответственно, он так и скажет: "Что-то в этой комнате не так" или "Что же тут не так?" или еще как-то. Но многие дают именно подстрочник "Да что с этой комнатой?" То есть, для русского уха достаточно коряво.
А вопрос мой состоит в том: имеет ли право переводчик адаптировать текст для русского уха/глаза или все-таки должен давать подстрочник?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переводчик просто обязан применять естественные средства второго языка для выражения смысла, заложенного в исходный текст. В разных языках разное деление на слова, разный порядок слов и разное их значение в разных сочетаниях. Факт перевода с чужого языка должен быть по возможности незаметен, но без ущерба для смысла и возможной для конкретного текста точности (без ухода в "изложение содержания").

Подстрочник же в учебных материалах по некоторым языкам (например, китайскому) полезен для демонстрации грамматических отличий изучаемого языка. В отдельных случаях узкоспециального перевода, делаемого для специалиста (когда с ним согласовывается текст) можно в дополнение предоставить ему подстрочники вызвавших сомнение фрагментов (термины и выражения с ними).

Answer (score 2):

Ну вообще-то профессионально занимающиеся переводом таких вопросов не должны задавать.
Переводчик в общем-то соавтор произведения, он вправе выбирать нужный ему стиль, руководствуясь самыми разными соображениями, от требований издателя, до личных отношений с автором оригинала.
Но прежде всего, конечно, во главу угла должна ставиться адекватность переложения текста. Так что подстрочник - это не перевод. Другое дело, насколько справедливы ваши претензии в конкретных случаях. Я большой беды в переводе реплики героя как "Что это с комнатой" не вижу. А что там в оригинале-то? What's happening in the room?

Comment: Если бы я занимался переводами профессионально, то и не задавал бы)) Я - любитель, просто взявшийся переводить тексты, в том числе, субтитры к некоторым фильмам, для которых нет официального перевода. И кое-что еще.